# VueJS: How to remove first and last quotation marks of a user submitted string?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a VueJS app with a form with pre-populated data. A textarea element has some data like so shown on the UI

Note: (sorry I do not have enough rep points yet to attach screen shot):

[screenshot of UI text area element with quote marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZrKP.png)

I can't modify the way the backend is serving the data.

Thus, is there a good way where I can remove the FIRST and LAST quotation marks from a string? I dont' want to touch the inner text in case the user is adding quote marks within.

Expected output of **'Hello World, welcome to "fooWorld!"'** shall be **Hello World, welcome to 'fooWorld!'**

Here's a real world example of how I am using the data in my SPA:

```
data() {
    return {
        entryNotes: this.post.entryNotes  //<--- this is the data I need to format
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a quick regex to get rid of start and end quotes?

```
data(){
    return {
        entryNotes: this.post.entryNotes.replace(/^"/,"").replace(/"$/,"")
    }
}
```

The first regex looks for the start of the string (symbolized by ^) and then a quotation mark.  The second regex looks for a quotation mark and then the end of the string (the end of string is symbolized by $).

You could also do this:

```
str.match(/^"?(.+?)"?$/)[1]
```

This one looks for the start of the string (^) followed by a ", but the ? makes it optional.  Then the parenthesis captures .+ which means match anything.  The ? before the end of the parenthesis means stop matching as soon as you can. Then it says look for a quotation mark, but the next question mark says "possibly", then look for the end of the string ($).